# How do I read this data in R

Tags: r

I was trying to read a txt data in R, but when I input this txt to R using read.table. The data is not really split. Is there any way to split data by number of columns.The data looks like below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Instead of an image of your data,  please provide a text version that we can cut and paste.

Comment: Please also provide the code of what you have tried and got, and what you desired, so we can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You can read fixed width files using `read_fwf` from the `readr` package.